# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' in python

Tags: python

I've written this simple script, but it gives me an error when it gets to the math part. I've tried setting it to an int(), but that also doesn't work.

```
import os
from fractions import Fraction
def cls():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
def pause():
    programPause = raw_input("Press the <ENTER> key to continue...")

def header():
    print("Slope Calculator")
    print("Daniel Meskin")
    print("BSD Licen    ce")
    print("<------------------    >")

header()
x1 = input("(")
gcoord="("+x1+","
cls()
header()
y1 = input(gcoord)
gcoord="("+x1+","+y1+"),("
cls()
header()
x2 =input(gcoord)
gcoord="("+x1+","+y1+"),("+x2+","
cls()
header()
y2 = input(gcoord)
gcoord="("+x1+","+y1+"),("+x2+","+y2+")"
cls()
header()
print(gcoord)
slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
slopef=Fraction(slope)
print(slope+"|"+slopef)
pause()
```

Edit: I realised my mistake, sorry for the confusion :(

Comment: `input` returns a `str` which must be converted to an `int`. The function `int()` can take a string and return the integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert `str` to a number type to do `-` operation on them:

`slope = (float(y2)-float(y1))/(float(x2)-float(x1))`

(or you may use `int()` instead of `float()` depending on your demand)