# Arithmetic operation on Array causes TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, arrays, string, dtype

I have dataset in **Array** as shown below.

```
P=array([['984.6'],
       ['983.9'],
       ['983.2'],
       ...,
       ['7.8'],
       ['7.8'],
       ['                  ']], dtype=object)
```

While I'm doing any arithmetic operation then it giving an error. e.g. I have tried `Sub = P - P` then

```
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`
```

Kindly suggest for same

Comment: Are you sure you want *strings* in the array? Not actual numeric values?

Comment: The error message pretty much says it all.  There are no numbers in your array.  They values are all strings.  `'7.8'` is  a string.  `7.8` is a number.  They aren't the same.  You can't subtract strings.  You need to convert the strings to numbers, e.g. `float('7.8')`, which is `7.8`.

Comment: @sushanth `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Comment: @TomKarzes I have tried Also this one `float(n) for n in s.split()]` but not work

Comment: Instead try `P=array([[984.6],[983.9],...)` Without the single-quotes around the numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603948/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-str-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is filled with strings instead of floats. It's throwing an error, because you are trying to perform an arithmetic operation on string variables.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing the error because, you cant subtract two strings, you first need to type cast those strings into integer using int(str) or float using float(str)

Comment: I have tried with `int(P)` or `eval(P)` but `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Answer (score 0):

@Addy

you cant type cast a 2-d directly using int(p), you have to iterate over it
another method to typecast the entire array is

```
new_array =  P.astype(np.float)
```

hope, this will work for you  :)